# ios - How to find people using my app within a wifi network

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Hi I  want to  find all people using my app within a same network, say if its a wifi network then i want to get all people using my app in that particular network.

their profile data existing in my database (mySQL) with their location. I can get the users As per location But my Question is to find them as per network. Any ideas how to start to do that?

Comment: Implementing Bonjour might be one option, and it can probably be done using GameKit also

Comment: Thanks for the response, I never used Bonjour before. Do you have any sample code or link  That will find the IP address of all the device Using the same wifi network ? @rokjarc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im not saying using Bonjour (Zeroconf) is the best way to achieve what you want - but you can certainly achieve your goal using it.

Bonjour is used in two ways:
- publishing a service
- detecting (browsing for) available services

For your task you'd have to do both.

One basic description can be found here: [Bonjour Overview and its application in iOS](http://mobile.siliconindia.com/mobile-expert/Bonjour-Overview-and-its-application-in-iOS-eid-130.html)

If you decide to use Bonjour then you'll find a lot of documentation on [Bonjour for Developers](https://developer.apple.com/bonjour/)

Basically, you need to publish a service: [Bonjour Programming > Section 18.2. Publishing a Service](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/iphone/9780470918029/bonjour-programming/publishing_a_service#X2ludGVybmFsX0h0bWxWaWV3P3htbGlkPTk3ODA0NzA5MTgwMjklMkZwdWJsaXNoaW5nX2Ffc2VydmljZSZxdWVyeT0=)

The publishing class (usually `appDelegate`) should be also a `NSNetService` delegate.

```
NSNetService *netService; //an ivar or a property

//creating and publishing a service
netService = [[NSNetService alloc] initWithDomain:@""
                                             type:@"_yourservicename._tcp."
                                             name:@""
                                             port:9876];
//if your app actually acts as a server port: should be it's port,
//otherwise it could be any free port

netService.delegate = self;
[netService publish];
```

You should also handle delegate methods (and some `appDelegate` methods):

```
-(void)netService:(NSNetService *)aNetService
    didNotPublish:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSLog(@"Service did not publish: %@", dict);
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    //---stop the service when the application is terminated---
    [netService stop];
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    //---stop the service when the application is paused---
    [netService stop];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [netService publish];
}
```

And browse for existing services: [Bonjour! (cocoanetics)](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/11/bonjour/)
(you'll only need the bottom part of the page)

```
serviceBrowser = [[NSNetServiceBrowser alloc] init];
serviceBrowser.delegate = self;
[serviceBrowser searchForServicesOfType:@"_yourservicename._tcp." inDomain:@""];

- (void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser 
    didFindService:(NSNetService *)aNetService moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"foundServices"];
    [_foundServices addObject:aNetService];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"foundServices"];
 
    NSLog(@"found: %@", aNetService);
}
 
- (void)netServiceBrowser:(NSNetServiceBrowser *)aNetServiceBrowser 
    didRemoveService:(NSNetService *)aNetService moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"foundServices"];
    [_foundServices removeObject:aNetService];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"foundServices"];
 
    NSLog(@"removed: %@", aNetService);
}
```

PS: Bonjour might be tricky to start with but it is certainly a useful knowledge.

Depends on what user experience exactly you want. A good alternative to Bonjour would most certainly 
be `GameKit` ([GKPeerPickerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKPeerPickerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) where user can actually
select to which devices (peers he wants to connect to).
This should work in Wi-Fi or via BlueTooth.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed Answer. I will try to work on it and let you know. @rokjarc

Comment: No problem and good luck! Let me know if you run in any problems.

Answer (score -1):

One way of doing service discovery is to have your program listen on a port and then doing a broadcast on that port when you want to be discovered or poll for other entities.
Something along these lines.

```
 socket = listen_and_stuff()
 others = do_broadcast()
 while(run)
     if time to update
         others = do_broadcast
     if received request
         reply with info about self
```

But, broadcast depends a bit on router settings, subnetworks and so on so it *might* not work in all cases.

Comment: To be very honest i m very new to iOS development, Though your answer seems to be very correct, i cant able to understand it where to start and where to use this Code ? Can you please explain a bit ? thanks for your time. @dutt

Comment: this is rather cross-platform, what you want to do is read up on how to use sockets.